# How to force display update in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe application where I want to center the board when the view has been loaded.

I've made a `centerBoard()` function that gets called in `viewDidLoad()`.
This is the code of the function:

```
func centerBoard() {
    print("centerBoard() triggered")
    let centerX = (outerView.frame.size.width)/2
    boardView.center = CGPointMake(centerX,250)
    if boardView.center == CGPoint(x: centerX,y: 250) {
        print("centerBoard() successful")
    }
    boardView.setNeedsLayout()
    boardView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

However, the board doesn't change place when the view is loaded, only when the test button is pressed, despite running the exact same code. I made the `if` statement to check if the board's center has been updated, and it prints successful everytime, both when the view has loaded and when the button is pressed.

Comment: let centerX = outerview.bounds.width / 2 try this

Comment: the outer view frame size is not established on view did load when autosizing is enabled,  you need to do it after the constraints are applied, so you may wanna do it in viewdidappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out to the console the center coordinates in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Probably your settings are overridden by autolayout, viewDidLayoutSubviews is called a couple of times after viewDidLoad was called.
Set the center for your view through the autolayout system, or turn off the autolayout for the xib/storyboard if you don't want to use it.

Comment: It worked calling my function in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Yes, but note that this is just a workaround, not the proper solution! You should learn the autolayout system instead of using the old framing system. http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2